# WordPress alphabetical A-Z custom post type post result display

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, alphabetical

How to display WordPress custom post type result alphabetical letters or pagination?

For a example I have a post type called "homeless". Under homeless there are 50 states (categories). There are 259 listing under Arkansas. I want to show a alphabetical letters a-z in the Arkansas category. For example if someone click on letter "B" it will show all listing under "Arkansas" begin with letter "B". Can anyone have a suggestion or php code for this?

Please see the image:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far. You are expected to do your research and make an attempt at the problem before posting here. Take a look at [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and update your question with the code you have tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details of the exact problem so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook is what you're looking for without writing any custom queries

```
function hl_sort_schools( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        if ( $query->is_post_type_archive('homeless') ) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'title');  
            $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
        }       
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hl_sort_schools' );
```

I'm assuming your CPT is called `homeless` and the location names are stored in `post_title`

Something like this should help (not sure if all locations are schools or not, you can adjust the function name accordingly)

Comment: Carlos Reyes, yes  my cpt is "homeless '  .thank you for the help . i will follow this. once again thank you very much :)